How to get a list of all nodes that have multiple revisions?
Generally, I prevent revisions for all content types, and each node has just one revision. However, I may have made a mistake somewhere along the way; also, I have recently converted the content type of some nodes and noticed that each node conversion creates a new revision for that node even though I have already blocked the option to create new revisions for nodes.
To ensure that I don't miss out on any nodes that have multiple revisions, so I can then manually delete all undesired revisions, how can I generate a list of all nodes that have multiple revisions?

The duplicate question is "how do I get the list of revisions for a single node" whereas this question is "how do I get the list of nodes that have multiple revisions?" This should be re-opened.

@PatrickKenny – Node Revision Restrict in the other question's answers can do that job.

The purpose is still to delete node revisions, so it is a duplicate.

To ensure that I don't miss out on any nodes that have multiple revisions, so I can then manually delete all undesired revisions.
